# TextView - resize view bounds to fit the text after scaling the text

Tags: android, textview, resize, scaling, view-bound

I am scaling down text size from 30sp to 18sp. But as show in the images below the height and width of text view remains same after scaling, leaving too much space below and above the text.

**Original:**

[image: Original]

**Scaled:**

[image: Scaled]

**Scaled with background color:**
[image]

**How can I resize the view bounds (at least height) so as to fit the new text size and avoid extra space?**

I searched but everywhere I found "how to resize text to fit the view bounds". **I need to resize view bounds to fix the text size.**

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.bizlers.soulcube.client.subtitlebehavoir.HeaderView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_view_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <!-- Subtitle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_view_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</com.bizlers.soulcube.client.subtitlebehavoir.HeaderView>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: did you try wrap_content to layout_height of textview ? Seems it is fixed now in your current code.

Comment: @ArthTilva Added the layout file in the question.

Comment: @cgr Yes, I am using layout_height=wrap_content only still facing the same issue.

Comment: As you have android:gravity="left|center_vertical" we cannot confirm that you have textview of that big size, size may be due to your custom parent view. So for that try by applying background color to textview, so that we can measure actual size of TV.

Comment: I have used wrap_content only in parent view too. The bounds shown in the images are for TextView "Title" only.

Comment: @ArthTilva Ya, you are right. I tried to set background color to text view and it is working as expected. Space left below and above are outside the textview.

Comment: Still I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Let me add another snapshot with background color to both text views.

Comment: @ArthTilva Added snapshot of how it looks like after setting background color to both text view. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try to have LinearLayout. because this is might due to "com.bizlers.soulcube.client.subtitlebehavoir.HeaderView"

Comment: How? I mean, HeadeView is extended from LinearLayout only. Check the link for detail code. https://github.com/harcoPro/SubtitleCoordinatorLayoutExample

Comment: I think its scaling down text size along with background color. TextView bound are intact.